# Como iniciar un proceso de simulación cuando la "Cola" tenga mas de 1 elemento?

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Tengo una conexión entre Unity y Anylogic (software que se utiliza para simulaciones), en la cual se utiliza datos que extraigo de Anylogic para ejecutar en Unity y replicar la misma simulación, el error que tengo ahora es que el aumentar la velocidad de reproducción en Anylogic, la información también llega de manera mas rápida en Unity, por lo cual acelera el proceso de información y hace que Unity se quede desincronizado e incluso pegado al aumentar la velocidad de reproducción en mas de un x25, este error que se produce es posible de arreglar, o es netamente de la capacidad de Unity? Adjunto código donde tengo implementado la "Cola", la cual almacena los datos recibidos, ojo que esta se va actualizando cada nueva información que le llega por protocolo udp.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using UnityEditor;
using static JSONReader;

[Serializable]
public class RealTimeItem
{
public GameObject Object;
public int NetID;
public Vector3 Position;
public Vector3 Target;
public float TimeReach;
public float TimeReachNext;
public bool change;

public float velocidades;

public Agente agent;
}
public class UDPClient : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<RealTimeItem> items;


public static UDPClient instance;
public int portListen = 4444;
public string ipSend = "";
public int portSend = 5555;

public GameObject[]  notifyObjects;
public string messageToNotify;

//private string received = "";

private UdpClient client;
private Thread receiveThread;
private IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
private IPAddress ipAddressSend;

public float TimeStamp = 1;


Queue<string> Cola = new Queue<string>();
//let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main;


public bool SetData(Agente ag)
{
    if (getObjWithID(ag.id) == null) return false;
    RealTimeItem itemUse = items[GetID(ag.id)];
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(ag.id);

    GameObject obj = getObjWithID(id);

    /*
    if (ag.coordenadas.Count > (ag.coordenadas.Count - 2))
    { 
        itemUse.Position = ag.coordenadas[ag.coordenadas.Count - 2]; 
    }
    */

    itemUse.Position = ag.coordenadas[ag.coordenadas.Count - 1];
    itemUse.Target = ag.coordenadas[ag.coordenadas.Count - 1];

    itemUse.TimeReach = ag.tiempos[ag.tiempos.Count - 1];
    itemUse.TimeReachNext = ag.tiempos[ag.tiempos.Count - 1];

    itemUse.velocidades = ag.velocidades[ag.velocidades.Count - 1];
    itemUse.change = true;


//  Debug.LogError("Checking: " + itemUse.NetID + "|||AGID: " + ag.id);
    //  obj.transform.position = itemUse.Position;
    return true;
    
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    foreach(var xItem in items)
    {
    //  xItem.Object.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(xItem.Object.transform.position, xItem.Position, TimeStamp * Time.deltaTime);
    //  xItem.Object.transform.LookAt(xItem.Target);
    }
}

public int GetID(int SearchID)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.NetID.Equals(SearchID)) return items.IndexOf(item);
    }
        return 0;
}

public GameObject getObjWithID(int SearchID)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.NetID.Equals(SearchID)) return item.Object;
    }

    return null;
}


public void Awake ()
{
    instance = this;

    //Check if the ip address entered is valid. If not, sendMessage will broadcast to all ip addresses 
    IPAddress ip;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse (ipSend, out ip)) {

        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (ip, portSend);

    } else {

        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Broadcast, portSend);

    }

    //Initialize client and thread for receiving

    client = new UdpClient (portListen);

    receiveThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (ReceiveData));
    receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
    receiveThread.Start ();
    
}

void Update()
{

    while (Cola.Count > 0)
    {
        var reciev = Cola.Dequeue();

        Debug.Log("UDPClient: message received \'" + reciev + "\'");

        //Notify each object defined in the array with the message received
        foreach (GameObject g in notifyObjects)
        {
            g.SendMessage(messageToNotify, reciev, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

        }

    }
}

//Call this method to send a message from this app to ipSend using portSend
public void SendValue (string valueToSend)
{
    try {
        if (valueToSend != "") {

            //Get bytes from string
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (valueToSend);

            // Send bytes to remote client
            client.Send (data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
            //Debug.Log ("UDPClient: send \'" + valueToSend + "\'");
            //Clear message
            valueToSend = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        Debug.LogError ("Error udp send : " + err.Message);
    }
}

//This method checks if the app receives any message
public void ReceiveData()
{

    while (true)
    {

        try
        {
            // Bytes received
            IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);
            //Bytes into queue
            Cola.Enqueue(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
            
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error:" + err.ToString());
        }
        
    }
}

//Exit UDP client
public void OnDisable ()
{
    if (receiveThread != null) {
            receiveThread.Abort ();
            receiveThread = null;
    }
    client.Close ();
    Debug.Log ("UDPClient: exit");
}
    
}
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta, me gustaría poder obtener la manera de tener en la "Cola" más de un elemento antes de que la simulación se realice en el Unity.

Comment: Si el propósito es crear un multijugador o algo parecido, sé que se utilizan técnicas como interpolación y predicción de movimientos. Deberías investigar sobre el tema.

Comment: @Mateo No, el propósito no es crear un multijugador ni nada parecido, para los movimiento de los agentes si utilizo técnicas de interpolación como el "Lerp", sin embargo, no puedo predecir movimientos porque son información que leo al momento, de hecho de eso mismo trata la pregunta, como puedo guardar información que se va leyendo en esa Queue.

Comment: Yo veo 2 posibilidades: 1) Asumes el desface, es decir Unity reproduce los datos a la velocidad que tu estimes conveniente, y si Anylogic envía más datos, estos quedarán encolados. Es decir, mientras más pase el tiempo habrá una diferencia mayor entre lo que Unity procesa y lo que Anylogic envía, pero no se pierde nada. La otra forma es que se pierdan datos. Por ejemplo tú quieres ir de (1) a (7), y en envías toda la secuencia de 1 en 1 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), en este tipo de problemas, si tienes el (3) aun sin procesar y te llega (4), descartas el 3 porque viene a ser irrelevante

Comment: @Yussef entonces, no hay ninguna posibilidad de que se ejecute la animación a la misma velocidad de Anylogic?, porque por lo que vi, lo que pasa ahora es una combinación de ambas posibilidades, no se pierden pero no las lee todas iguales.

Comment: Yo no soy experto en el tema (ni nada parecido), pero en algún momento leí sobre el tema cliente servidor en juegos y lo que tu planteas es el primer problema, el de mantener el sincronismo en la comunicación, y más o menos se soluciona como te lo señalaba (además de técnicas de interpolación cuando es el caso contrario, se va más lento). Por otro lado tú me hablas de "animación", pero resulta la animación está intrínsicamente ligados a los FPS y los FPS están limitados por el procesador, por la tarjeta de video y por la pantalla. Creo que un computador muy bestia da unos 280FPS máximo....

Comment: Para iniciar un proceso cuando la lista tenga más de un elemento solo tendrías que verificar si `Queue.Count > 1`. A lo mejor prefieres hacer que cada cierto tiempo se hagan los cambios. Para eso podrías usar `Time.time`, un cronómetro o un Coroutine en el que devuelves `new WaitForSeconds()` o algo así.

Comment: ... Pero te hablo de esos computadores que da componente vale una millonada, lo normal son 60FPS. Y además tienen el límite del ojo humando que creo que también anda por los 60FPS. Además ya se empieza a ver una animación fluida desde los 24FPS. Es decir, si tu envías más de 60 datos por segundo para animar es un desperdicio y si envías menos de 24 la animación no va fluida.

Comment: @Yussef no sé cuál es el límite pero se que si te acostumbras a un monitor de 144 hz vas a notar la diferencia con uno de 60. Es más sutil que de 60 a 30, pero la hay.

Comment: @Mateo La verdad es que en mi experiencia es como tú dices, pero antes de dar el dato lo busqué en internet y salían 60FPS. No obstante, el punto no es número exacto, el fondo es que no puede enviar una cantidad ingente de datos por segundo, porque eso no se va a Animar, uno podría procesar esos datos para sacar estadísticas u otro fin, pero para el mero propósito de una animación no tiene sentido. Ahora bien, si él está mandando 50 datos por segundo y eso no se anima, ahí hay un problema

Comment: Por otro lado, hace una prueba en la función `Update` cambia el `While` por un `If` y me cuentas si cambia en algo la situación

Comment: @Yussef con un if de `if (Cola.Count > 1)` basta, o mejor que sea >0 ?

Comment: `if (Cola.Count > 0)`. A ver qué pasa, me cuentas!!!

Comment: @Yussef la verdad ahora no se paraliza el Unity, sin embargo, va con un desfaz, tal como indicaste en tu primera posibilidad

Comment: Siempre existirá un delay entre el que manda y el que recibe (aunque se ejecute todo en la misma maquina) lo que tienes que ir viendo es si ese delay aumenta progresivamente. Puedes hacer en el `Update` un `Debug.Log(Cola.Count);` para ir viendo si la Cola crece progresivamente, si no lo hace es que está resuelto el tema

Comment: @Yussef al darle a la simulación, obviamente aparece 0 ya que no le llega nada, al iniciar al otro lado, se genera desde 4 al 0, o del 8 al 0, dependiendo de cuantos elementos agregue, aunque a veces pasa de 1-4-3-2-1-0 en ese orden

Comment: Me parece que está perfecto, problema sería que siguiera subiendo el número (nunca volviera a cero).  De aquí en más, si quieres disminuir el delay, tienes que preocuparte en simplificar el dato que se envía y como se procesa, debes entrar al mundo de la micro optimizaciones